# how to show function f is integrable or not

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

Here if $f$ is a measurable function on [0,1], define $G(x,y)$ $$G(x,y)=f(x)-f(y),$$
If we know $ G(x,y)\in L^1([0,1]\times[0,1])$, then $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ or not? If not, can we give a counterexample?

First we know  $ G(x,y)\in L^1([0,1]\times[0,1])$, so by Fubini Theorem,$$\int_0^1\int_0^1G(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x)-f(y)dxdy=\int_0^1f(x)dx-\int_0^1f(y)dy=0.$$
$\int_0^1\int_0^1|G(x,y)|dxdy=2\int_0^1\int_0^y |f(x)-f(y)|dxdy$.  But I don't know how to use the above equation to prove $|f|\in L^1([0,1])$.  I guess we can find a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One part of Fubini's theorem is that if $H \in L^1([0,1]\times[0,1])$, then for almost all $y\in [0,1]$ the function $h_y \colon x\mapsto H(x,y)$ belongs to $L^1([0,1])$.

So we know that $x\mapsto f(x) - f(y)$ is in $L^1([0,1])$ for almost all $y$.

But if $h\in L^1([0,1])$, then $h+c\in L^1([0,1])$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$), and since $f(y)$ is finite when $x\mapsto f(x)-f(y)\in L^1([0,1])$, it follows that indeed $f\in L^1([0,1])$.

So we have the result $G\in L^1([0,1]\times [0,1]) \iff f\in L^1([0,1])$.

We obtain the identity

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \lvert G(x,y)\rvert\,dx\,dy = 2\int_0^1\int_0^y \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\,dx\,dy$$

by splitting the integral into two parts, changing the order of integration in one part, and renaming, due to the symmetry of $G$:

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \lvert G(x,y)\rvert\,dx\,dy
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\,dx\,dy + \int_0^1\int_y^1 \lvert f(x) - f(y)\rvert\,dx\,dy\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\,dx\,dy + \int_0^1\int_0^x \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\,dy\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\,dx\,dy + \int_0^1\int_0^x \lvert f(y)-f(x)\rvert\,dy\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^y \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\,dx\,dy + \int_0^1\int_0^y \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\,dx\,dy.
\end{align}$$